# Subset and compare on two columns

Tags: r

I have a table made up of three columns. A person identifier, a column of event type (A or B) and a column of dates when the event happened. 
This is shown here:

```
Person  Event   EventDate
1   A   22/03/15
1   A   22/05/15
1   B   12/12/15
1   B   12/12/15
2   B   01/13/12
2   B   02/03/12
2   B   03/08/14
2   A   05/09/14
3   B   02/02/02
3   A   03/05/14
3   B   03/06/14
3   A   17/11/15
3   A   17/02/16
3   A   18/05/16
3   A   23/06/16
```

I want to subset the data. The subset should capture all `eventA` within a `Person` that occur after the first `eventB` The output would be:

```
Person  Event   EventDate
2   A   05/09/14
3   A   03/05/14
3   A   17/11/15
3   A   17/02/16
3   A   18/05/16
3   A   23/06/16
```

I think the problem I have is knowing how to compare rows for a Person based on two column comparison (Event and EventDate).

```
This is the dput of the original data above
structure(list(Person..Event...EventDate = c("1   A   22/03/15", 
"1   A   22/05/15", "1   B   12/12/15", "1   B   12/12/15", "2   B   01/13/12", 
"2   B   02/03/12", "2   B   03/08/14", "2   A   05/09/14", "3   B   02/02/02", 
"3   A   03/05/14", "3   B   03/06/14", "3   A   17/11/15", "3   A   17/02/16", 
"3   A   18/05/16", "3   A   23/06/16")), .Names = "Person..Event...EventDate", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'Person', we `order` the 'Person', 'EventDate' (after converting to `Date` class), then `if` the cumulative sum of 'B' 'Event' is 1 for the first elements, then get the row index of 'A' 'Event'  and use that to subset the original dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[order(Person, as.Date(EventDate, '%d/%m/%y')),
      if(cumsum(Event == "B")[1]==1) .I[Event == "A"],  by = Person]$V1]
#      Person Event EventDate
#1:      2     A  05/09/14
#2:      3     A  03/05/14
#3:      3     A  17/11/15
#4:      3     A  17/02/16
#5:      3     A  18/05/16
#6:      3     A  23/06/16
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(Person, as.Date(EventDate, '%d/%m/%y')) %>% 
    group_by(Person) %>% 
    filter(first(Event == "B") & Event == "A")
#     Person Event EventDate
#   <int> <chr>     <chr>
#1      2     A  05/09/14
#2      3     A  03/05/14
#3      3     A  17/11/15
#4      3     A  17/02/16
#5      3     A  18/05/16
#6      3     A  23/06/16
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Event = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A"), EventDate = c("22/03/15", 
"22/05/15", "12/12/15", "12/12/15", "01/13/12", "02/03/12", "03/08/14", 
"05/09/14", "02/02/02", "03/05/14", "03/06/14", "17/11/15", "17/02/16", 
"18/05/16", "23/06/16")), .Names = c("Person", "Event", "EventDate"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `sqldf`. I'm assuming the data is sorted by date.

```
> library(sqldf)

> 
 v1 <- structure(list(Person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Event = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A",
     "B", "A", "A", "A", "A"), EventDate = c("22/03/15", "22/05/15", "12/12/15", 
    "12/12/15", "01/10/12", "02/03/12", "03/08/14", "05/09/14", "02/02/02", 
"03/05/14", "03/06/14", "17/11/15", "17/02/16", "18/05/16", "23/06/16")), .Names 
= c("Person", "Event", "EventDate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
        > v1$EventDate <- as.Date(v1$EventDate , '%d/%m/%y')
        > v2 <- v1[v1$Event == 'B' , ]
        > v2 <- v2[ !duplicated(v2$Person) , ]
        > v3 <- v1[v1$Event == 'A' , ]
        > sqldf("select a.* from v3 a , v2 b where a.EventDate > b.EventDate And a.Person = b.Person")
          Person Event  EventDate
        1      2     A 2014-09-05
        2      3     A 2014-05-03
        3      3     A 2015-11-17
        4      3     A 2016-02-17
        5      3     A 2016-05-18
        6      3     A 2016-06-23
> v1
           Person Event  EventDate
        1       1     A 2015-03-22
        2       1     A 2015-05-22
        3       1     B 2015-12-12
        4       1     B 2015-12-12
        5       2     B 2012-10-01
        6       2     B 2012-03-02
        7       2     B 2014-08-03
        8       2     A 2014-09-05
        9       3     B 2002-02-02
        10      3     A 2014-05-03
        11      3     B 2014-06-03
        12      3     A 2015-11-17
        13      3     A 2016-02-17
        14      3     A 2016-05-18
        15      3     A 2016-06-23
```